# Recursively moving files to root folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, file-management

I am more used to using unix shell than CMD, and I am not really sure how to get this to work. I have a directory with several other sub-directories that contain .xml files. I would like to move all the files recursively to the root directory. I know with unix this done like so:

```
find FOLDERPATH -type f -name '*.xml' -exec mv -i {} FOLDERPATH \;
```

Yet I can't seem to find something that will work in the same way. XCOPY looked promising, but it doesn't copy only the folders, it copies the whole structure, thus I get these sub-directories that I don't want again. Has anyone got any other suggestions?

Comment: In the bash it is  `mv -i /folderpath/**/*.xml /somewhere` ;)

Answer (score 5):

This will work from the CMD prompt.  Run it in the folder you want the files to be moved to, and it will process the sub-directories in that folder.

It does not provide a mechanism to handle filename collisions elegantly.

```
for /R /D %f in (*) do move "%f\*.xml" .
```

and this will work in a batch file.

```
@echo off
for /R /D %%f in (*) do move "%%f\*.xml" .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set FOLDERPATH=...
for /R "%FOLDERPATH%" %%f in (*.xml) do move "%%~ff" "%FOLDERPATH%"
```